# Need to connect to my IBM Bluemix Virtual Servers from my laptop (Using ssh or any remote connecting method)

Tags: ibm-cloud, ssh-keys, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, coreos, virtual-server

I have created a virtual server which is under the Infrastructure category of the IBM Bluemix. When I go to the Bluemix portal I can see that the Virtual Server is running and is in connected state. Virtual Server is running the CoreOS. Now I want to connect to this server remotely using my laptop. I created SSH keys in my local machine and added the Public key to the Bluemix. And then I tried to connect remotely using ssh to the Virtual Server with its private key file. But I couldn't connect. It gives a connection refuse error. Is there anyone who have connected to a virtual server like this or know about this?

Comment: Here is a link to the Virtual Server documentation that might help: http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/topic/virtual-server. Also, I found this specific article, which might help: http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/articles/connect-your-vsi-using-vnc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoreOS uses the `core` user instead of `root`, did you specify that?

```
ssh core@1.2.3.4
```

Comment: Once I tried to connect to core user it worked. And I had a issue with my network too. My network was restricting the connection. Got it solved. Thanks @Rob